# Spring JMX - exporting a map of key value pairs

Tags: java, spring, jmx

Is it possible, ideally using the spring JMX annotations, to export a map of key value pairs where the key is used as the exported attribute name?

If so, how?

Thx.

Comment: Hi

I'm faced with the same issue - how quick did you find this task?

Comment: Sorry, I abandoned it. skaffman's answer scared me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface that Spring uses to build JMX metadata for a given bean is `MBeanInfoAssembler`.  This is a very general inerface, allowing any possibility that JMX itself will support, including exposing an arbitrary map as a set of JMX attributes.

However, implementing that interface is quite a chore - the JMX API is a bit of a pig. Spring provides a number of implementations of various complexity, but they're all geared around exposing javabean-style Spring beans.  Even the more generic of the implementations, `AbstractMBeanInfoAssembler`, assumes getters and setters to get the JMX attribute values.

So you *could* write your own implementation of `MBeanInfoAssembler`, but it's going to be difficult.